# retrieve IApplicationBuilder and IWebHostEnvironment in another part of your application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is it possible to get this `IApplicationBuilder app` and `IWebHostEnvironment env` somewhere else in the application, later when it's already booted up.

I'm assuming it's a singleton that I can retrieve somewhere else too, via some application context etc.

I'm using net core 3.0

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if `IWebHostEnvironment` is registered with the service container?

Comment: how do I check that?

Comment: Try and inject it somewhere would probably be the easiest way. If I had VS2019/.NET Core 3, I'd check myself, but alas I don't.